# Call parent function inside of child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, csv, ifstream

```
class Parent;
class Child;

Parent *parent;

ifstream inf("file.csv");
inf >> *parent;

//in parent class
friend istream& operator>> (istream &is, Parent &parent) {
  return parent.read(is);
}

virtual istream& read(istream &is){
  char temp[80];
  is >> temp;
  // then break temp into strings and assign them to values
  return is;
}

//virtual istream& read
```

It reads and assigns only first two values to the Parent class.`Child` class has `Parent` class values + 3 of its own.

How can I call I call parent's `read()` function and then child's `read()` function so parent's function reads first 2 fields in the file and child reads next 3 fields?

I know it's a matter of syntax; I just can't figure how to do that.
I have tried calling `Parent::read(is)` inside the child read class, I've tried calling it before the child's `read()`; I have tried `read(is) >> temp` but none of them worked. When I called `Parent::read(is)` and then `is >> temp`, parent `is` would return all 5 values of the file.

Comment: all your `a,b,c,d,e,g,df,ds,vd,bn` variables.. this is bad style. please, write something like this: `in_file` (can't understand, but suppose it is input file) or `input_file` or `inputFile` or etc...

Comment: IIRC Parent::method() should work.

Comment: I think that Parent::method() would only invoke a static method of Parent. To invoke the Parent version of read I think you'd need to cast your Child to Parent and then invoke read via the Parent ref, as in `Child c; Parent(c).read() /* should invoke Parent method */; c.read() /* should invoke Child method */;`.  I'm assuming here that Child inherits from Parent although the declarations in the question didn't indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation you typically have Child override the `read` function in Parent. This allows the derived class to call the original function in the parent prior to applying it's own logic.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void read(istream &s)
    {
        s >> value1;
        s >> value2;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void read(istream &s)
    {
        Parent::read(s);  // Read the values for the parent

        // Read in the 3 values for Child
        s >> value3;
        s >> value4;
        s >> value5;
    }
};
```

To perform a read operation"

```
// Instantiate an instance of the derived class
Parent *parent(new Child);

// Call the read function. This will call Child::read() which in turn will
// call Parent::read() 
parent->read(instream);
```